# How to hide the content that's outside the parent div with aside?

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="h-screen w-32 bg-gray-300">
        <aside class="grid grid-cols-2 bg-yellow-400 w-64 h-full">
            <div class="bg-red-300">
                One
            </div>
            <div class="bg-green-300">
                Two
            </div>

        </aside>
    </div>
```

There is a parent `div` with fixed width (`w-32`) and a child `aside` that is double the width of the parent. So I want only one half, the one that's inside the area of the parent `div` to be shown

How can I do that?

Comment: So there should be only visible ONE? Or shoulld be only visible two?

Comment: My plan is to toggle between the two with some animation/js (moving them left and right) later, so I want to show only one every time. It can be One for the example

Answer (score 4):

If you are planning to toggle between those two-child div, You can do something like this.

- Make one div to display none.
- and make another one to display block(I used active class).
- set main parent div(h-screen) to overflow-hidden.
- and toggle between active class on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".h-screen aside div").click(function(){
    $(".h-screen aside div").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.h-screen{
  overflow:hidden;
}
aside div {display:none}
aside div.active {display:block}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h-screen w-32 bg-gray-300">
        <aside class="grid grid-cols-2 bg-yellow-400 w-64 h-full">
            <div class="bg-red-300 active">
                One
            </div>
            <div class="bg-green-300">
                Two
            </div>

        </aside>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So you can just simple add style to toggle you want hide at this moment :

sample code:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="h-screen w-32 bg-gray-300">
        <aside class="grid grid-cols-2 bg-yellow-400 w-64 h-full">
            <div style="display:none;" class="bg-red-300">
                One
            </div>
            <div class="bg-green-300">
                Two
            </div>

        </aside>
    </div>
```

Just added :`style="display:none;"` inside ONE - in result the only Two is visible :) You can do that in both ways ofc.

and resul looks like :
[image]

@EDIT 1 :

HTML code:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="h-screen w-32 bg-gray-300">
        <aside  style class=" bg-yellow-400 w-64 h-full">
            <div id="one" class="one">
                One
            </div>
            <div id = "two"class="two">
                Two
            </div>

        </aside>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.two {
  
  background: red;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 250px;
    position: absoulte;
}

.one {
  
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  position: absoulte;
}
```

JS code to show and hide ONE and TWO

```
let subsWrapper = document.getElementById("one");
subsWrapper.remove();
document.getElementById("element_id").remove();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm planning to use the One and Two as Menu and Submenu, and make them move left and right. But when I use hidden, I don't know how can I animate this left/right movement (Like One is pushing Two and vice-versa)

Comment: @Stackerito then instead of using `display: none` set the width to 0 and animate that or `transform: translate` and animate that.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass I did it when I had one div, but now the purpose to have the effect of the menus "pushing" each other (For example one side is main category menu and when you click it it's the sub-category menu). So now I somehow need to hide the part the is going to the right when I animate that's why I try to wrap it inside a div with fixed width and maybe use `overflow-x: hidden`  but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Edited my answear , you can use Javascript to show and hide element by id.   If you want to hide just change on : document.getElementById("two"); or document.getElementById("one");